# Scala - case classes inheriting types

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, mixins

Is there a way to have a case class accept types defined in a trait that it mixes in?
When I try what I would do with ordinary classes, it fails:

```
trait myTypes{
    type aType = Array[String]
}

abstract class ParentClass extends myTypes{
    //no issue here
    val a:aType = Array.fill[String](7)("Hello")
}

//error: not found: type aType
case class ChildClass(arg:aType) extends ParentClass

//error: not found: type aType
case class ChildClass2(arg:aType) extends myTypes
```

Not sure why Scala would choose to behave this way, but I would appreciate some help in circumventing this annoying error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the type alias is out of scope:

```
// error: not found: type Bar
class Foo(val bar: Bar) { type Bar = String }
```

Instead try:

```
class Foo(val bar: Foo#Bar) { type Bar = String }
```

Comment: (commenting for the record:)this also works with inheritance: `case class ChildClass(arg:ChildClass#aType) extends ParentClass`.

Comment: Yes, as the child class inherits both type and regular members of the parent.